# What is the best strategy to change my Princess' mood?

Tags: long-live-the-queen

My Princess is always depressed or lonely. It seems to be very difficult to change her mood with any sort of quickness, and weekend activities seem to make it very difficult to put her into certain moods. For example, pressure seems to be very difficult to add to without significant adds to other areas.

**What is the best strategy for manipulating the mood of my princess?**

[image: Mood chart]

Comment: That's part of the game difficulty, actually.

Comment: @Shadur Yes, I'm aware. It is actually very well balanced. But, given the options, I am looking for a good strategy to manage the situation.

Answer (score 4):

Unlock more weekend activities and you'll have an easier time. If you study Dance you'll eventually get Ballroom as an activity and then you can raise Pressured more conveniently.

Answer (score 2):

Your princess' mood is influenced by her weekend activities and by your decisions during special events. Sometimes, those event results are logical (for example imprisoning someone can raise your anger or depression), but sometime they are really hit or miss. You will get the hang of it with more playthroughs.

As for the weekend activities, you have access to the standard ones from the start. You can gain access to more by leveling your skills (e.g. dancing for ballroom, reflexes for sports, horses for hunting and more). And keep in mind that the effect of weekend activities can change depending on your current mood - visiting (for example) the dungeon when willful will make you more angry and willful, while visiting them while yielding will make you more yielding and afraid.